# JavaScript код - причина бана

Tags: javascript

Каким образом сделать так, чтобы, когда я баню пользователя, мне выпрыгивало окно с просьбой ввести причину бана? Как сделать так, чтобы та причина, которую я ввел, выводилась на странице бана у пользователя?

Answer (score 1):

На кнопку повешайте событие - prompt, кажется... то есть нажали первый раз кнопку - вылезло окно, ввели и там пошло, как надо... кстати, вы потом будете класть в базу данных, не так ли?